# How to Do Custom Autocomplete function for ext Combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an extjs combobox which has autocomplete enabled. Right now the matching is done by the starting of the list. I want to do a word matching in the full string rather than the start. For eg, if the list is

Code Complete

Platform Code

Code Master

Right now when I type "Code", it show "Code Complete" and "Code Master"

Rather I also want to get the Platform Code also in the list, along with other two.

Let me know how I can do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`anyMatch`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-anyMatch) option.